# How to partition running_sum calculation in Tableau?

Tags: sql, tableau-api, partition, level-of-detail

I currently am trying to accomplish the following SQL within Tableau's LOD + table expressions:

```
SELECT PATIENTID,CLINIC_ID,DATE,QUANTITY,SUM(QUANTITY) OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENTID ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS RUNNING_TOTAL
FROM "MY_SCHEMA".MY_SUMMARY
ORDER BY PATIENTID,DATE ASC
```

Normally, I would just use the above in a Custom SQL Datasource but I need it in LOD + Table calculations because I want the starting date to be customizable from a param I have on the dashboard.

I have tried the following:

```
RUNNING_SUM({fixed [Patientid],[Clinic Id]: SUM([Quantity]) })
```

But this gets the following error:

```
All fields must be aggregate or constant when using table calculation functions or fields from multiple data sources
```

I can successfully do:

```
RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Quantity]))
```

But of course that is just the running sum overall, and not per patient/clinic.

I've also tried:

```
{fixed [Patientid],[Clinic Id]: RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Quantity])) }
```

But that gets the error:

```
Level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the ATTR function.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the running sum calc, as you already have it, but you'll also need to create a composite key between Patient ID and Clinic ID, which would go on the Detail shelf, so you're able to instruct Tableau to restart the running sum calculation using the field.

Comment: Very interested in this answer. Can you show a similar example visually so I can replicate something similar?